# Looking for a Example using nhibernate validation with WPF

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, validation

I have a library that was written using nHibernate and I am trying to connect it to a WPF application. Looking for a way to integrate the validation without tightly coupling the code... Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still looking for a solution, try looking [here](http://hightech.ir/SeeSharp/mvvm-validation-with-nhibernate-validator)

Comment: Sorry, the link was broken when I moved my blog. Use this one [link](http://hightech.ir/SeeSharp/mvvm-validation-with-nhibernate-validator)

Comment: And this is why you add the relevant parts to your *answer*. =)